# Blur event handler is blocked by jquery preventDefault() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onblur

I'm working on an interactive web application, currently set up on http://picselbocs.com/projects/goalcandy (user: demo@demo.com, password: demo). It allows you to drag items containing images and/or text from the left sidebar onto the workspace on the right and resize/edit them, among other things.

To edit text on created objects, you simply click on a text field, either title or comment. That `<span>` element gets replaced with a `<textarea>` through which you can then edit the content. When the "blur" event occurs, the textarea disappears and its value is added to the `<span>` element. *The problem is that clicking on the object's image (if it has both an image AND text fields) prevents the "blur" event from firing.*

I've used the following snippet to prevent images from being dragged separately from the parent objects, and just found out that this is what's causing the issue. But I can't not use this, and at the same time I have to not use it:

```
$(document).on('mousedown dragstart', 'img', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

How can I get around this problem and allow the onblur event handler to run even when clicking the image, but at the same time maintain the default behavior prevention?

PS: The `alert('blur')` call allows me to monitor when the event fires.

Comment: i clicked on image and "blur" fired, which browser do you use?

Comment: @Denis Ermolin Sorry, I forgot to save the script with that snipped un-commented. Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use some variable say

```
var locks = {}; 
locks.textarea_lock = false;
```

Then clicking on textarea set `locks.textarea_lock = true;` In image handler check this lock:

```
$(document).on('mousedown dragstart', 'img', function(event) { 
    if (locks.textarea_lock) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

In "blur" handler unlock variable `locks.textarea_lock = false;`.

Comment: No luck, the behavior didn't change.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I tweaked this idea a bit and it was just what I needed. Best wishes!